# Search List of JTokens for text value

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a list of JTokens and I need to determine if any of the tokens contain a certain value. For example, I need to know if the list of tokens contains the word "Checking". The first JToken in the list contains a value of "Checking 11010000".

Here are some attempts that actually compiled.

```
var test1 = testlist.FirstOrDefault( i => i.Contains( "Checking" ) ); // returns null
var test2 = testlist.Any( x => x.Contains( "Checking" ) ); // returns false
var test3 = testlist.TrueForAll( x => x.Contains( "Checking" ) ); // returns false
var test4 = testlist.TrueForAll( x => x.Children().Contains( "Checking" ) ); // returns false
var test5 = testlist.Any( x => x.Children().Contains( "Checking" ) ); // returns false
var test6 = testlist.All( x => x.Children().Contains( "Checking" ) ); // returns false
var test7 = testlist.Find( x => x.Contains( "Checking" ) ); // returns null
```

How can I search the JToken list for the value without iterating the list and inspecting each token?

**Update:**

Here is a snip of the relevant JSON source:

```
    {
       ...
       "Rows":{
          "Row":[
             {
                "ColData":[
                   {
                      "value":"Checking 11010000",
                      "id":"35"
                   },
                   {
                      "value":"232.40"
                   },
                   {
                      "value":""
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "ColData":[
                   {
                      "value":"Savings 11020000",
                      "id":"36"
                   },
                   {
                      "value":"800.00"
                   },
                   {
                      "value":""
                   }
                ]
             }
    ...
    }
```

This is how my list is declared

```
var testlist = PriorMonth.SelectTokens( "$..ColData[*].value" ).ToList();
```

This gives me a list that looks like 
[image]

Comment: 1) Why do you want to search the list *without iterating the list and inspecting each token*?  What do you mean by that?  2) Can you provide a [mcve]?  3) Will the tokens be atomic `JValue` values or can they they be containers where the search word is deeply nested?

Comment: Well, essentially I have two lists and I want to find out if one list contains a value from the other list. If both lists contain the value we take one action, if the lists do not both contain the value we take another action.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of testlist in your sample code please.

Comment: Sure, I added some updates @DylanNicholson

Comment: How do you access the string value of a single `JToken`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test the value of each `JToken`, not the contents of the `IEnumerable<JToken>` where `Contains` compares for a matching `JToken`:

```
var hasChecking = testlist.Any(jt => jt.Value<string>().Contains("Checking"));
```

Comment: Thanks @NetMage. Using what you posted I was able to get things working!